# ngx-timepicker-field shows no 02:00

Tags: angular, luxon

Since today, the timepickers in our Angular application do not show 02:00 anymore, but two times 03:00 instead. We are using ngx-material-timepicker for these.
The app is being used in Germany and we moved to daylight saving time tonight, so I suspect it has something to do with it:

[image]

If I input 02:00 manually in the corresponding input field, the time is set to 03:00 instantly:

[image]

Here is the code I use:

```
  <div *ngIf="isTo" class="input-row">
<label class="input-label">{{ 'booking.departureTime' | translate }}: <sup>*</sup></label>
<div class="input-box">
  <div class="timepicker-air--wrapper">
    <ngx-timepicker-field
      class="timepicker-air"
      [ngClass]="{ 'timepicker-air--err': !data.time }"
      [defaultTime]="data.time"
      [(ngModel)]="data.time"
      [format]="24"
      name="time"
      required
      (timeChanged)="data.time = getModifiedTime($event)"
    ></ngx-timepicker-field>
    <mat-icon class="timepicker-air__icon" (click)="data.time = null">clear</mat-icon>
  </div>
</div>
```

And this is how the getModifiedTime function looks like that is called on timeChanged:

```
export function correctNgxComponentTime(data: string) {
 if (data && data.substring(0, 2) === '24') {
    return data.replace('24', '00');
  } else {
    return data;
  }
}
```

That one is just for reference though - I can debug that and I see that as soon as the app gets there, the time is already set to 03:00 instead of 02:00.

So I managed to track it down a bit further, and found this one line in ngx-material-timepicker.js [line 466]:

```
const parsedTime = TimeAdapter.parseTime(time, opts).setLocale(TimeAdapter.DEFAULT_LOCALE);
```

After this line, the timestamp is wrong, it is indeed converted to an epoch timestamp with hour 03:00 instead of 02:00 (the timestamp I currently get is `1648342800000`, which even says GMT+2 as time zone, which is the one I'm in).

The `TimeAdapter.DEFAULT_LOCALE` results in `en-US` (it should actually be `de-DE`, as the app is being used in Germany).
However, if I run this line in the debugger as `TimeAdapter.parseTime(time, opts).setLocale('de-DE')`, I get exactly the same (wrong timestamp).

The time picker component seems to use Luxon, and I found the place where the conversion of the time to epoch time happens:

```
function parseDataToDateTime(parsed, parsedZone, opts, format, text) {


var setZone = opts.setZone,
      zone = opts.zone;

  if (parsed && Object.keys(parsed).length !== 0) {
    var interpretationZone = parsedZone || zone,
      inst = DateTime.fromObject(Object.assign(parsed, opts, {
      zone: interpretationZone,
      // setZone is a valid option in the calling methods, but not in fromObject
      setZone: undefined
    }));
    return setZone ? inst : inst.setZone(zone);
  } else {
    return DateTime.invalid(new Invalid("unparsable", "the input \"" + text + "\" can't be parsed as " + format));
  }
} // if you want to output a technical format (e.g. RFC 2822), this helper
// helps handle the details
```

What I observe here that again, the locale is set to `en-US`, but I do not know how to change this.

What I also tried is setting the locale of the time picker to `de-DE`, but this doesn't fix it (locale in luxon.js from above is still `en-US`):

```
NgxMaterialTimepickerModule.setLocale('de-DE')
```

as described here:
https://github.com/Agranom/ngx-material-timepicker/blob/master/README.md#internationalization